# Comparing two columns and returning most similar columns python

Tags: python, list, matching

I have two data frames.

df1 looks like below.

```
List1
[apple, banana]
[carrots]
[for, spinach, mushrooms, the]
```

df2 looks like below.

```
List2
[apple, garden]
[spinach, smoothie]
[garlic, carrots]
[carrots]
[mushroom, the]
```

I want to match the lists in df1 to the lists in df2 and produce a similarity score.

So desired output looks something like below.

```
List1                              List2              Sim_Score
[apple, banana]                    [apple, garden]    0.52
[carrots]                          [carrots]          1.0
[for, spinach, mushrooms, the]     [mushrooms, the]   0.49
```

I can handle the similarity score part. My question is how can I find the best match for every row in List1 using List2?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the goal here, but it seems like you're trying to solve a version of the [stable marriage problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is how to find the best match for every row in `List1` using `List2`.

To answer it, I will mock up a similarity score algorithm just to get numbers that are different for different pairs being analyzed for similarity.

Here is some code that does what you're asking in terms of identifying, for each row in `List1`, the match in `List2` with the "best" (namely highest) similarity score:

```
        List1 = [
            ['apple', 'banana'],
            ['carrots'],
            ['for', 'spinach', 'mushrooms', 'the']
        ]
        List2 = [
            ['apple', 'garden'],
            ['spinach', 'smoothie'],
            ['garlic', 'carrots'],
            ['carrots'],
            ['mushroom', 'the']
        ]
        def get_sim_score(a, b):
            return (Counter(a) & Counter(b)).total() * 2 / (len(a) + len(b))
        Sim_Score = [max(((b, get_sim_score(a, b)) for b in List2), key=lambda x:x[1]) for a in List1]
        print(f"{'List1' : <40}"+f"{'List2' : <25}"+"Sim_Score")
        [print(f"{str(List1[i]) : <40}"+f"{str(Sim_Score[i][0]) : <25}"+f"{Sim_Score[i][1]}") for i in range(len(List1))]
        return
```

Output is:

```
List1                                   List2                    Sim_Score
['apple', 'banana']                     ['apple', 'garden']      0.5
['carrots']                             ['carrots']              1.0
['for', 'spinach', 'mushrooms', 'the']  ['spinach', 'smoothie']  0.3333333333333333
```

The key line of code can be expanded (for easier understanding) as follows:

```
        #Sim_Score = [max(((b, get_sim_score(a, b)) for b in List2), key=lambda x:x[1]) for a in List1]

        Sim_Score = []
        for a in List1:
            cur_b, cur_max = None, 0
            for b in List2:
                cur_score = get_sim_score(a, b)
                if cur_b is None or cur_score > cur_max:
                    cur_b, cur_max = b, cur_score
            Sim_Score.append((cur_b, cur_max))
```

Comment: @Cohen Fisher, did this answer work for you? Do you need any more help with this?